# Is a batsman out if they stop a ball spinning onto the wicket with their bat?

Tags: rules, cricket

If the batsman hits the ball and the ball spins and goes to the wicket, if he stops the ball with the bat, is he out or not out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please consider adding appropriate tags to your questions in future - this both makes it easier for other people to find your question, and increases the chance that you will get a good answer as more people interested in it will find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

He is not out. He is allowed to use the bat to guard his wicket if the ball is rolling back to the wicket

### **34.3 Ball lawfully struck more than once**

The striker may, solely in order to guard his/her wicket and before the ball has been touched by a fielder, lawfully strike the ball a second or subsequent time with the bat, or with any part of his/her person other than a hand not holding the bat.

Comment: While this is correct, could you add a reference to the appropriate Laws of Cricket which support this answer?